# How to get Proguard to overwrite the original jar with the optimized one?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, proguard

I'm having trouble trying to get Proguard to overwrite the original jar generated by Maven with Proguard's optimized version. This is a section of my POM.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>proguard</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <proguardVersion>4.11</proguardVersion>
                <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
                <outjar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</outjar>
                <options>
                    <option>-keep class **</option>
                    <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses</option>
                    <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers</option>
                </options>
                <libs>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
                </libs>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                    <version>4.11</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Note these two lines:

```
    <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
    <outjar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</outjar>
```

I'm trying to get Proguard to use the original jar as the input and output it to that same jar, but what I get is the original jar being suffixed with "_proguard_base" and the optimized jar being named how it should be. This only happens if the inJar and outJar options are the same.

Also, i'm using Eclipse with the Maven plugin for this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard can't write the output jar to the same file as the input jar. It seems that the Maven plugin tries to solve it by renaming the input jar. You may have to take this into account in your build process.

Comment: in that case, is there a way i can get rid of the original jar?